# How to get file data and other form data sent in POST request in Node Js

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, body-parser

I am sending form data values using Postman as given here. [Postman Request](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LsiL2.png).
I am making use of NodeJS server in the backend to get the data from this POST request.

The code for my `app.js` file is given below.

````
require('dotenv').config();
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const path = require('path');
const port = process.env.PORT || 8080;
const app = express();

app.use(bodyParser.json({
  limit: '50mb',
}));

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
  limit: '50mb',
  extended: true
}));

const { multerUploadOneFile } = require(path.resolve(__dirname, 'helpers', 'multerConfig'));

app.post('/upload', function (req, res) {
  // **Here I need to get the other parameters in the request body, i.e ```userId```, ```fileType```  
  console.log(req.body);
  multerUploadOneFile(req, res, function (error) {
    if (error) {
      return res.status(401).send({
        status: 'failure',
        message: error.message
      });
    }
    return res.status(200).send({
      status: 'success',
      message: 'successfully uploaded file.',
    });
  })
});
````

I am logging the request body in `/upload` api endpoint but I am not able to get anything. Please let me know how can I get the `req.body` in callback of `/upload` api endpoint.

Comment: `req.body` for `multipart/form-data` requests is populated by Multer.

Comment: So, I need to pass some multer middleware ?. Please let me know as I am new to Node JS.

Comment: You have to pass it to `multerUploadOneFile` before you can use `req.body`

Answer (score 0):

`body-parser` doesn't support multi-part bodies.

`multer` (which you're correctly using) does, however it needs to execute and parse the request before you'll be able to access anything.

`multerUploadOneFile` needs to execute before you have acceess to `.body` or `.file`.

```js
app.post('/upload', function (req, res) {
  multerUploadOneFile(req, res, function (error) {
       console.log(req.body, req.file);
```